# initialize adc_channel_t via variable

Tags: esp-idf

i am new to the Esp Idf and a beginner programmer and I would like to initialize the adc adc_channel_t via a pointer string but I get an error "conflicting type qualifiers"

can someone help me how to initialize adc_channel_t via own variable so that I can pass in that variable via a own function wehre I can change the channel as argument.

this is the code

const char *ptr ="ADC_CHANNEL_0";
static const adc_channel_t ptr;

adc1_config_channel_atten(ptr, atten);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `adc1_config_channel_atten()` can be found in the [ESP IDF programming guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html?highlight=adc1_config_channel_atten#_CPPv425adc1_config_channel_atten14adc1_channel_t11adc_atten_t).

First of all, you are declaring the `ptr` variable twice with two different types. That doesn't work. You can declare the variable only once.

Second, you'll see from the documentation that `adc1_config_channel_atten` expects the enum type [adc1_channel_t](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html?highlight=adc1_config_channel_atten#_CPPv414adc1_channel_t) as type of the first parameter. You can not pass a `const char*` there. If you have to use a string for whatever reason, you need to write a custom conversion function which takes the string as an argument and returns a variable of the type `adc1_channel_t` (or an error value, if something can go wrong).

Hope this helps! Let us know in the comments if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it helped I will try to write a that function which returns

Comment: an variable of type adc1_channel_t which is of type enum if I understood that right.